# What is the meaning of "waddnat"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, songs

In the negro spiritual *Jonah and the Whale*, I found the word *waddnat:*

> ...
> Now the Lord made a whale, long and wide
> Lord, Lord waddnat a fish
> And he swallowed up Jonah, hair and hide
> Lord, Lord waddnat a fish
> Mmm, Lord, mmm, Lord
> ...
>
> [From AZLyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/louisarmstrong/jonahandthewhale.html)

What is the meaning of *waddnat*? Is it like a combination of multiple words?

I couldn't find any reference on the internet.

Comment: *Wasn't that*, perhaps?

Comment: @Lawrence almost certainly, given the context.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I thought of that as well. But how is one supposed to *guess* that? An obvious way is the pronunciation... How is this technique called?

Comment: I think it's a form of phonetic spelling.

Comment: I'd agree with Lawrence and Pink and there doesn't need to be any technique. One *is* supposed to *guess* that for the simplest reason; *waddnat* is as likely to be a mistake as a form of phonetic spelling and either way, no rules could apply.

Comment: Agree! Actually, doing another quick search I found other versions with *Wasn't that* instead of *waddnat*. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't guess the meaning, and you're meant to, the technique is called bad transcription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Wasn't that*.

Some English dialects substitute *d* for *s*, often when immediately preceding an *n* or *th*. So *idnit* for *isn't it*, *whodat* for *who's that*.

Comment: I thought that the [d] came from voicing [t]...

Comment: @as4s4hetic: In "who's that", the [d] is at least partly from the [ð] of "that". I don't see an example of [d] from [t] in any of the phrases mentioned on this page. Another example of /zn/ to /dn/ is "bidness" for "business"

Comment: "wadn't" and "idn't" are apparently used in some British accents also: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/idnt-wadnt-isnt-wasnt.2432198/

Comment: @sumelic oh, that's interesting!